# How to determine if the user clicked a link from a parent event handler?

Tags: javascript

If I bind a click handler to an ancestor of the element I'm interested in tracking clicks on, how can I determine if the user clicked the element?

e.g.

```js
function clickHandler(ev) {
  // how to determine if a link was clicked from here?
  // and also get a reference to that <a> element
  // i.e., I want to filter out clicks on <td>s and <span>s, *unless*
  // a <span> (or other element) is contained in an <a>, then that still counts!
  console.log('click!');
}
```

```html
<table onClick="clickHandler(event)">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
    <td><span>not link</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>also not a link</td>
    <td><a href="#"><span>complex link</span></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: tie the click event to the links using something like `$('table').on('a span', function(ev){});`

Comment: @JamieD77 Nope, I specifically do not want to bind the event handler to the element itself because the body of the table is dynamic.

Comment: thats why you tie the even to the table by using `$('table').on()` it won't matter whats in the table.. you filter out what you want to handle in the `.on('click', 'filter', 'eventhandler)`

Comment: So basically you're trying to create a delegated event handler **without using jQuery** ?

Comment: @adeneo Essentially, yes.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4uunrbhu/

Comment: @JamieD77 I can't bind the event using jQuery. This is actually going into a React component, and React uses old-school `onClick` attributes.

Comment: oh gotcha.. would be useful to see in the description :)

Comment: @JamieD77 Well I did set it all up in the description. Was looking for a fill-in-the-blank exactly where my comments were. Anywho, I figured something out so no worries.

Answer (score 2):

We can search up the DOM until a match is found.

e.g.

```js
function clickHandler(ev) {

  var el = closestAncestor(ev.target, 'a', ev.currentTarget);

  if (!el) {
    console.log('not found');
    return;
  }

  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log('found', el.dataset.secret);
}

/**
 * Search up through the DOM tree until an element matching the selector is found.
 * 
 * @param {Element} target Element to start searching up from
 * @param {string} selector Query selector (passed to {@link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches|matches})
 * @param {Element=} context Stop searching if this element is hit
 * @returns {Element|null} Found element or null
 */
function closestAncestor(target, selector, context) {
    while (target) {
        if (target.matches(selector)) {
            return target;
        }
        if (target === context) {
            return null;
        }
        target = target.parentElement;
    }
    return null;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-secret="should not be found">
  <table onClick="clickHandler(event)">
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#" data-secret="simple link">link</a>
      </td>
      <td><span>not link</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>also not a link</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-secret="complex link"><span>complex link</span></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the target of the event. In this case.

```
ev.target
```

You'll want to compare this not only to the current element, but also up the dom tree, as in your second example, the span may be the target, but the link is a parent, so you can assume that the link was clicked. You may also want to be more specific than targeting all links by applying classes to the links you wish to target.

That should give you the element that was actually clicked.

Comment: `ev.target` is a `<span>` in the "complex link" example.

Comment: Good point. You'll want to see if it's parents is a link. I will update to reflect this.

Comment: Or its parent's parent, or its parent's parent's parent...it should search up until the `<table>` and then stop. i.e., if the table itself is wrapped in an `<a>` then that doesn't count.

Comment: If the table itself is wrapped in an `<a>`, then the user still did click an `a` element. If you want to be more specific, you'll want to apply a class to the `<a>` elements you're hoping to target.